# Why am I getting to Java.io.IOException stream closed?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I  am unsure of why I am getting this error. I tried searching for an answer on the net  but was unsuccessful.

Below is the partial code where the error is taking place. I am sending a header and upon getting a successful response of 200 I will carry out the rest of my code.

```
URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;        
        try{


//Create connection

        url = new URL(targetURL);
        Log.i(TAG,"Connecting to : "+targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        //connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11");


        connection.setRequestProperty("x-device-displayheight", device_displayheight );

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            String rep = connection.getResponseMessage();
            int respcode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String line;

        try{                        
            if(respcode == 200 ){// Everything is ok                            
                if(is != null){
                    //response.append(is.toString());   

                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                        Log.i("Output",line);
                    }

                }
                else{
                    Log.i("Nothing to parse","");
                }


            }
            else{// bad response from server
                Log.i("Bad Response", rep +" : "+respcode);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

//stack trace

```
04-04 13:14:41.668: W/System.err(23046): java.io.IOException: stream closed
04-04 13:14:41.668: W/System.err(23046):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.AbstractHttpInputStream.checkNotClosed(AbstractHttpInputStream.java:69)
04-04 13:14:41.668: W/System.err(23046):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.FixedLengthInputStream.read(FixedLengthInputStream.java:41)
04-04 13:14:41.668: W/System.err(23046):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:248)
04-04 13:14:41.668: W/System.err(23046):    at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:130)
04-04 13:14:41.668: W/System.err(23046):    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:357)
04-04 13:14:41.668: W/System.err(23046):    at com.ameba.api.network.Client.executePost(Client.java:95)
04-04 13:14:41.668: W/System.err(23046):    at com.ameba.api.activityClasses.Login$connectToServer.doInBackground(Login.java:190)
04-04 13:14:41.672: W/System.err(23046):    at com.ameba.api.activityClasses.Login$connectToServer.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
04-04 13:14:41.672: W/System.err(23046):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
04-04 13:14:41.672: W/System.err(23046):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-04 13:14:41.672: W/System.err(23046):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-04 13:14:41.672: W/System.err(23046):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
04-04 13:14:41.672: W/System.err(23046):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
04-04 13:14:41.672: W/System.err(23046):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

Comment: Please show us the stack trace.

Comment: @SteveKuo I just added the stack trace

Comment: call `connection.connect();`  before `InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();`
 line

Comment: Don't see anything functionally wrong with your code.  Can you tell us a little about the env you are running in?  proxies? firewalls? web-server?

Comment: @imrankhan tried that, the problem still persists.

Comment: @TimJones . No proxies , I am able to connect the web no problem and I am getting the correct response code. The issue seems to be with my InputStream

Comment: @Fabii :thanks for fast response

Comment: @Fabii :what error u are getting same or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");` Seem to  have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing things in a different order and loop only if you have valid streams :

```
URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;        
        try{


//Create connection

        url = new URL(targetURL);
        Log.i(TAG,"Connecting to : "+targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        //connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11");


        connection.setRequestProperty("x-device-displayheight", device_displayheight );

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            String rep = connection.getResponseMessage();
            int respcode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String line;
                    BufferedReader br = null;

        try{            
                            //use a constant below instead of 200           
            if(respcode == 200 ){// Everything is ok                            
                if(is != null){
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                    //response.append(is.toString());   

                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                        Log.i("Output",line);
                    }

                }
                else{
                    Log.i("Nothing to parse","");
                }


            }
            else{// bad response from server
                Log.i("Bad Response", rep +" : "+respcode);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
                      if( br != null ) { br.close() };
                    }
```